# httpErrors not working on localhost in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, web-config

I have added following in my webconfig. It works when site is hosted to IIS but not when I run locally. It gives me error of wrong web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom"  defaultPath="ShowError.aspx" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Post the error details here. Is that invalid XML or something else?

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application

Comment: Are you sure that `ShowError.aspx` exist on project's root folder? Check application folder permissions, current user permissions & show error code given by local IIS event log.

Comment: Yes. It does exist and if I redirect to error page from another page. That way it works.

Answer (score 3):

The `defaultPath` attribute is locked by default, which causes the `500.19` error. You can either:

1. Unlock `defaultPath` by removing it from your `applicationHost.config`, which I do not recommend because then you'll have to configure this on every developer and production server.
2. Remove `defaultPath` and `defaultResponseMode` from `<httpErrors>` and specify `path` and `responseMode` on each `<error>`, like so:

   ```
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
       <clear />
       <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
       <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
       <error statusCode="401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
       <error statusCode="405" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
       <error statusCode="406" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
       <error statusCode="412" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
       <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
       <error statusCode="501" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
       <error statusCode="502" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="ShowError.aspx" />
   </httpErrors>
   ```

   It might seem excessive to specify each status code separately, but there is no other way when using `httpErrors`. I would recommend you to add `400` (Bad Request).

Some side notes:

1. You can omit `subStatusCode="-1"` because `-1` is the default value of `subStatusCode`.
2. If you're going to remove/replace all default IIS error pages, you might as well use `<clear />`.
3. You might want to remove `errorMode="Custom"` when you've got your error pages working, because this will hide error details from developers, slowing down productivity while debugging. A good error page is only returned for remote requests, which is what the default value (`errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly"`) will do.
4. If you can't get the error pages to work, try `responseMode="Replace"`. You also want to avoid using this in developer environments for the same reasons as the above.

Comment: Should be the top answer on the net! Looking for a good answer for a long time mainly due to so-called `Friendly URLs`. This works with those turned on.

Answer (score -1):

If you have custom error pages, try this:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Auto">
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/AccessDenied" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/InternalServerError" />
    </httpErrors>
```

If you want custom error pages on local, you can change *DetailedLocalOnly* to *Custom*.